# How do I feed a gas line through a kegerator without damaging the kegerator?

Tags: refrigerator

I am currently finishing my basement, and I built a bar with a built-in kegerator to dispense draft beer. The kegerator is able to fit three sixth barrel kegs (one third the size of a full half-barrel keg) and one gas tank for gas (such as CO2) to dispense the beer with. I have started getting into having Guinness on tap, which is dispensed with nitrogen, as well as nitro cold brew coffee. The problem with this is that when I have something with nitrogen on tap the extra nitrogen tank takes up extra room in the kegerator so that I can only have two items on tap.

To solve this I would like to drill a gas line feed into the side of my kegerator so that I can store the nitrogen tank outside of the kegerator and feed the gas through the side. My only problem is that I don't know how I can drill through the side of the kegerator while confidently knowing that I'm not going to hit any important parts such as a refrigeration coil. I've tried looking for diagrams of where the coils and everything are located for my model, but I couldn't find anything. I have also thought about only drilling partially and feeling around for important parts before going all the way through, but then I could still hit something, and if there is something in the way, then what? I would have a hole that I can't use for anything.

My kegerator is an Edgestar Built-in Kegerator. I can get the exact model if anyone thinks it is relevant.

Does anyone have any sugestions?

Comment: Sides and back are probably the most dangerous for hitting coils and ruining the unit(even just a nick).  It is not something to drill into blind.  Check edgestar site for support(manuals).

Comment: Traditional method with a Keezer (chest freezer kegorator) is a collar (insulated) between the door/lid and the freezer, so the hole is not actually in the refrigeration device. I find it odd that a device actually marketed as a kegorator does not have pre-drilled and plugged until you need them ports, safely located. In the door itself near the hinge side might work, with appropriate loops to permit movement when the door opens.

Comment: Can you just replace the CO2 tank with Nitrogen and use the Nitrogen for everything?

Comment: @gnicko Unfortunately CO2 beers must be dispensed with CO2 and cannot be substituted with nitrogen

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about appliance modification, not Home Improvement.

Comment: @FreeMan this is part of my project to finish my basement so wouldn't that be considered home improvement?

Comment: "Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances." is considered on-topic. Not sure a kegerator is a "major appliance" (though I suppose for some it may be), but this is modification, not maintenance or repair. Besides, at a minimum, it needs more detail about the problem according to 2 other users, so you may want to edit to include more details (pics and a link the the instructions are always nice). Maybe it'll get reopened... Of course, maybe someone will do your searching for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the cooling parts are on the bottom and associated with the fans (which you should be able to see). From there you can trace the coolant lines using the diagram. I would guess that the further toward the front door the less likely to encounter a refrigerant line.

The diagram can be found [here](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/model/3huhxd2awe-003268/edgestar-br7000ssod-wine-beverage-cooler-parts)

Comment: That's for the response! When I click the link I cannot find the diagram. I found a reference to the user manual, but I also couldn't find the diagram there. Is there a specific place I should be looking when I follow the link?

Comment: Click "Continue reading" then scroll down and to the right a little. Click "COOLER ASSY". I tried to post the diagram here but SE didn't like the graphics format.